# Confusing Segue Parameters in Swift, Maybe Legacy Way of Writing Things?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I was reading someone writing a performSegue method within a function like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    guard let annotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations.first else {return}
    selectedRestaurant = annotation as? RestaurantItem
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Segue.showDetail.rawValue, sender: self)
}
```

My question is that from other books I have read, including Apple's manual for XCode 12 as well I would have thought of writing something like this.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: showDetail, sender: nil)
```

I cannot comprehend the meaning/significance of adding `self` before `performSegue` and after `sender:` as they look redundant.

Likewise, I would have written `showDetail` as the Segue identifier simply. What are the `Segue.` and `.rawValue` before and after `showDetail` for? I don't seem to find anyone else teaching people write in that way.

Could it be that it is some sort of legacy way of writing Segue while I am reading books written in 2020 and/or 2021?

Thanks...!

Comment: You can omit the `self.` if you want. `self.` is only necessary inside a closure or when you have 2 variables with the same name

Comment: `sender: self` is because "The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue." [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue)

Comment: "This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue." <- in essence kind of sound like it is unnecessary and might as well use `sender: nil` in practice???

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` parameter is arbitrary and is for compatibility reasons with the `prepare(for segue:sender:)` method.

In a hard-coded segue the `sender` is either the `UITableViewCell` or the `UIViewController` depending on the connection.

In `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender` you can pass whatever you want. If you don't need the `sender` pass `nil` but you could even pass the `annotation` to get rid of the temporary property.

---

Regarding the identifiers a type safe and more sophisticated way to handle the identifiers is a protocol for example

```
protocol SegueHandlerType {
    associatedtype SegueIdentifier : RawRepresentable
}
```

and an extension which overloads the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:` method

```
extension SegueHandlerType where Self : UIViewController, SegueIdentifier.RawValue == String {
    
    func performSegue(withIdentifier segueIdentifier : SegueIdentifier, sender: Any?) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier.rawValue, sender:sender)
    }
    
    func segueIdentifer(for segue : UIStoryboardSegue) -> SegueIdentifier {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier, let segueIdentifier = SegueIdentifier(rawValue: identifier) else {
            fatalError("Invalid segue identifier \(segue.identifier!)")
        }
        return segueIdentifier
    }
}
```

The benefit is that the identifiers are enums which are checked at compile time.

Then you can adopt the protocol in a view controller and declare

```
enum SegueIdentifier : String {
    case pushDetail = "PushDetail"
}

...

performSegue(withIdentifier: .pushDetail, sender: annotation)
```

and in `prepare(for segue` you can check

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segueIdentifer(for: segue) == .pushDetail {
       let annotation = sender as! RestaurantItem
...
```